# Getting virtual function pointer through the virtual table

Tags: visual-c++, vtable

I'm trying to 'touch' an object layout that has a pointer to vTable. I'm getting a virtual function pointer by 2 options:

1. by traversing pointers from object pointer to virtual table pointer and then to the first function in this table.
2. simply by taking an address using & operator.

In both cases when I call a function through these pointers I get expected calling results. So in the output I see

```
Derived func
Derived func
```

But these function pointers are not equal and I don't know why. So for example

```
funcDerived = 0x00901ac3
derivedFuncPtr = 0x00901ab9
```

Does anybody have a thought why they are not equal? I use VS 2017 compiler.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func()
    {
        std::cout << "Base func" << std::endl;
    }
};


class Derived :public Base
{
public:
    virtual void func() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived func" << std::endl;
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    Derived obj;

    auto funcDerived = &Derived::func;

    unsigned int* objPtr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&obj);
    auto derivedVTablePtr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(*objPtr);
    auto derivedFuncPtr = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(Derived*)>(*derivedVTablePtr);

    derivedFuncPtr(&obj);
    (obj.*funcDerived)();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm just having fun) It is a curiosity.

Comment: The standard doesn't even require a class to have a vtable.   Admittedly, most modern implementations (compilers, etc) use vtables, but they are not required to.  In any event, the layout of the vtable, and the meaning of particular entries in it is highly compiler specific. And, even worse, compiler vendors are not required to document the layout of vtables, may change it arbitrarily between compiler versions, etc.   So, the only answers (unless you get a Microsoft compiler developer posting) will be guesswork, error-prone, and may not apply to past or present versions of your compiler

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But for me the question is more about how can I call the same function through different function pointers. I expect that a function body is a singleton in a memory and can be accessed through a single address.

Comment: @LameProgrammer _"how can I call the same function through different function pointers. "_ What do you mean? Same function code for different class instances? The `this` pointer is just an implicit parameter for these functions.

Comment: I mean that Derived::func() is placed somewhere in a memory. Lets say its address is 100. I can call it knowing only its address(I don't even need to know the function name). This is what I do in 1st case.
In the 2nd case I get Derived::func() address using & operator but it returns me different address not 100. Lets say 106. And I don't understand how can I call the same function through different adresses.

Comment: funcDerived does *not* point to func(), note how the debugger tells you about the "thunk".  It is the thunk function that actually dereferences the v-table, then jumps to func().  Thunks are necessary because the obj reference is not supplied until later, when you make the function pointer call.  It deals with the corner case of the base class not needing a v-table but the derived class needing one, and keeping it all work with Edit+Continue and incremental linking in effect.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant! I suspect that & operator might return something else but not func(). I didn't face with 'thunk' function before. Now I know what to read. Thank you!